# how can I scale each element separately?

Tags: jquery

Hi guys I have the following code where I am trying to scale each element on mouse over but it seems that only the first element is scaling. Any idea?

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/1rdoxe84/

JS

```
$('#playButton').hover(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("m-icon--hovered");    
}, function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("m-icon--hovered");
});
```

Comment: do you have the same id for all the elements?

Comment: Id needs to be unique in html, as per your question I suspect you are using multiple elements with the same id which will break your javascript.

Comment: My code looks like in https://jsfiddle.net/1rdoxe84/ but yes I am using the same id. But if I can't use the same id how shall I grab all elements with one function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's must be unique. If you have multiple `#playButton`, than only first one will ever work. Replace it with `class="playButton"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.playButton').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("m-icon--hovered");
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("m-icon--hovered");
  });
})
```

```css
.u-container {
  position: relative;
}
.u-line-height {
  line-height: 2.6;
}
.u-padding--none {
  padding: 0;
}
.m-button__icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 8px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.m-icon--play {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.m-icon--hovered {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="media" class="m-list">
  <li class="video u-container u-padding--none u-line-height">
    <img class="playButton m-button__icon m-icon--play" src="http://www.wayfm.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/playButton-150x150.png" />
  </li>
  <li class="video u-container u-padding--none u-line-height">
    <img class="playButton m-button__icon m-icon--play" src="http://www.wayfm.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/playButton-150x150.png" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selctor uses an Id selector (#). 
jQuery will always return only one element if the query uses the id (#) selector.
Use a class selector or another type of selector to apply your function to multiple elements.